# React native changing img with state Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

First sorry to guys because my eng level is very low.

I'm studying react native.
Try changing image with the state but is not working.
Error : null is not an object (this.state.admob)

**index.js**

```
   class HomeScreen extends React.Component {    
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {admob: require('../Img/admob1.jpg'), admobCount: 0};
   }

   _changeAdmob(){
       this.setState({
           if(admobCount = 0){
               admobCount: this.state.admobCount + 1;
               admob: require('../Img/admob1.jpg');
           },
           if(admobCount = 1){
               admobCount: 0;
               admob: require('../Img/admob2.png');
           }
       });
   }

   componentDidMount(){
       this.admobTimer = setInterval(
           () => this._changeAdmob(), 2000
       );
   }

   componentWillUnmount(){
       clearInterval(this.admobTimer);
   }

   render() {                          
     return (          
         <View style={styles.MasterContainer}>
             <NavBar navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
             <UserBar navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
             <View style={{height: 40,}}></View>
             <ButtonTab/>
             <Admob/>
             <TapBar/>
         </View>
     );
   }
  }

   class Admob extends React.Component{
     render() {
         return(
             <View style={{ flex: 1,alignItems: 'center',justifyContent:'center' }}>
                 <Image style={{ width: 350, height: 70 }} source={this.state.admob}></Image>                 
             </View>
         );
     }
  }
```

** I want to image change whenever 2 seconds.**

Comment: What about save url string directly to `this.state.admob` ?

Comment: I didn't check all the code, but from a quick glance, you are using '=' for comparison while you should use '===', and you use ':' for setting a value for variables while you should use '='. Change this and see what happens. [for example, instead of if(admobCount = 1) admobCount: 0; you should write if(admobCount === 1) admobCount = 0;]

The answer below is not less important, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the state on the component `<Admob admob={this.state.admob} />`

Add this on the `index.js`

```
<View style={styles.MasterContainer}>
          <NavBar navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
          <UserBar navigation = {this.props.navigation}/>
          <View style={{height: 40,}}></View>
          <ButtonTab/>
          <Admob admob={this.state.admob}/>
          <TapBar/>
</View>
```

> Admob.js change this.state to this.props

```
<Image style={{ width: 350, height: 70 }} source={this.props.admob}></Image>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
work it fine!
but my _changeAdmob method is not working..
i'm fixing it..

Comment: add this on function _changeAdmob().
 to this
_changeAdmob = () => {
....
}